# Summing numbers in two diffrent .txt file in Python

Tags: python, bigdata

I am currently trying to sum two .txt files containing each other over 35 millions value and put the result in a third file.

File 1 :

```
2694.28
2694.62
2694.84
2695.17
```

File 2 :

```
1.483429484776452
2.2403221757269196
1.101004844694236
1.6119626937837102
```

File 3 :

```
2695.76343
2696.86032
2695.941
2696.78196
```

Any idea to do that with python ?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! That sounds like a fun problem. You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you attempt solving it yourself first, and _then_ come back. When you do, describe what you've tried, what worked, and what didn't. And ask a _specific_ question indicating where you got stuck.  Good luck!

Comment: Use numpy or pandas, read, add, write

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you limited to python itself or can you use external modules e.g. numpy?

Comment: @mozway note that this is only possible here, because 35 million values is basically nearly negligible little data these days. If this was a large problem, so that reading all values into RAM became impossible, doing line-wise processing would be wiser.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you can also read files by chunks to benefit from both approaches ;)

Comment: how does one read a text-numbers containing file chunk-wise with numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy for speed.  It will be much faster than pure python.  Numpy uses C/C++ for a lot of it's operations.

```
import numpy
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

file_name_1 = path + '/values_1.txt'
file_name_2 = path + '/values_2.txt'

a = numpy.loadtxt(file_name_1, dtype=float)
b = numpy.loadtxt(file_name_2, dtype=float)
c = a + b
precision = 10
numpy.savetxt(path + '/sum.txt', c, fmt=f'%-.{precision}f')
```

This assumes your .txt files are located where your python script is located.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read, sum, and then write chunks of your file. 
Presumably all 35 million records do not stay in memory. You need to read the file by chunk. In this way you read one chunk at a time, and load into memory only one chunk (2 actually one for file1 and one for file2), do the sum and write into memory one chunk at a time in append mode on file3.

In this dummy example I put as chunksize=2, because doing tests on your inputs that are 4 long. It depends on the server you are working on, do some tests and see what is the best size for your problem (50k, 100k, 500k, 1kk etc).

```
import pandas as pd

chunksize = 2

with pd.read_csv("file1.txt", chunksize=chunksize, header=None) as reader1, pd.read_csv("file2.txt", chunksize=chunksize, header=None) as reader2:
    for chunk1, chunk2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
        (chunk1 + chunk2).to_csv("file3.txt", index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```